# C++ deleting pointers in a map

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, heap-memory

### Deleting heap items with a pointer in a map

I have this map:

```
map<string, Plaats*> plaatsen;
```

In a function I am adding places to this map like this:

```
Plaats * fromPlace = new Plaats(from);
Plaats * toPlace = new Plaats(to);
auto insertedFrom = plaatsen.insert(pair<string,Plaats*>(from,fromPlace));
auto insertedTo = plaatsen.insert(pair<string,Plaats*>(to,toPlace));
//delete from or to if they are not inserted
if(!insertedFrom.second){
    delete fromPlace;
}
if(!insertedTo.second){
    delete toPlace;
}
```

If the element is added to my map, I need to delete it in my destructor.

```
KortstePad::~KortstePad(){
    //delete every item in plaatsen
    for(pair<string,Plaats*> place : plaatsen){
        //Plaats *p = place.second;
        delete place.second;
        place.second = nullptr;
    }

    for(pair<string,Plaats*> place : plaatsen){
        Plaats *p = place.second;
        cout << (p == nullptr) << endl;
    }
}
```

It appears my code is not deleting my places, because this is the output of the program:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Why is this code not setting my pointers to nullptr? 
Am I setting a local variable to nullptr?

Comment: Why not use smart pointers?

Comment: `delete` will not change the content of whatever expression it is applied to, only the object pointed to by that expression is destroyed. You seem to know that, because you explicitly set `place.second` to null, but you are still asking about something in relation to `delete`. No, you only fail to set values in a loop, that's all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a reference to an element of the value type in the loop instead of using a copy. For example

```
for ( pair<const string,Plaats*> &place : plaatsen){
    //Plaats *p = place.second;
    delete place.second;
    place.second = nullptr;
}
```

Also take into account that the key shall have qualifier **const** `pair<const string,Plaats*>`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a reference to avoid copying.

```
for(pair<string,Plaats*>& place : plaatsen){
```

Edit:  I missed a `const` in the above answer.  So Vlad's answer is better.   Robinson's comment on my answer makes an even better answer.

Comment: Gives the following error :( : g++ -std=c++11 -g -c kortstepad.cpp
kortstepad.cpp: In destructor ‘KortstePad::~KortstePad()’:
kortstepad.cpp:19:36: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, KortstePad::Plaats*>&’ from expression of type ‘std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, KortstePad::Plaats*>’
  for(pair<string,Plaats*>& place : plaatsen){

Comment: I'd prefer *for(auto & place : plaatsen)* as it's less typing :).

Comment: Thanks for your hint :)